# MeanShift Clustering on dataset

Tags: matlab, matrix, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I have a numeric dataset and I want to cluster data with a non-parametric algorithm.  Basically, I would like to cluster without specifying the number of clusters for the input.  I am using this code that I accessed through the MathWorks File Exchange network which implements the Mean Shift algorithm.  However, I don't Know how to adapt my data to this code as my dataset has dimensions 516 x 19.

```
function [clustCent,data2cluster,cluster2dataCell] =MeanShiftCluster(dataPts,bandWidth,plotFlag)
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

%perform MeanShift Clustering of data using a flat kernel
%
% ---INPUT---
% dataPts           - input data, (numDim x numPts)
% bandWidth         - is bandwidth parameter (scalar)
% plotFlag          - display output if 2 or 3 D    (logical)
% ---OUTPUT---
% clustCent         - is locations of cluster centers (numDim x numClust)
% data2cluster      - for every data point which cluster it belongs to (numPts)
% cluster2dataCell  - for every cluster which points are in it (numClust)
% 
% Bryan Feldman 02/24/06
% MeanShift first appears in
% K. Funkunaga and L.D. Hosteler, "The Estimation of the Gradient of a
% Density Function, with Applications in Pattern Recognition"


%*** Check input ****
if nargin < 2
    error('no bandwidth specified')
end

if nargin < 3
    plotFlag = true;
    plotFlag = false;
end

%**** Initialize stuff ***
%[numPts,numDim] = size(dataPts);
[numDim,numPts] = size(dataPts);
numClust        = 0;
bandSq          = bandWidth^2;
initPtInds      = 1:numPts
maxPos          = max(dataPts,[],2);                          %biggest size in each dimension
minPos          = min(dataPts,[],2);                          %smallest size in each dimension
boundBox        = maxPos-minPos;                        %bounding box size
sizeSpace       = norm(boundBox);                       %indicator of size of data space
stopThresh      = 1e-3*bandWidth;                       %when mean has converged
clustCent       = [];                                   %center of clust
beenVisitedFlag = zeros(1,numPts,'uint8');              %track if a points been seen already
numInitPts      = numPts                               %number of points to posibaly use as initilization points
clusterVotes    = zeros(1,numPts,'uint16');             %used to resolve conflicts on cluster membership


while numInitPts

    tempInd         = ceil( (numInitPts-1e-6)*rand)        %pick a random seed point
    stInd           = initPtInds(tempInd)                  %use this point as start of mean
    myMean          = dataPts(:,stInd);                           % intilize mean to this points location
    myMembers       = [];                                   % points that will get added to this cluster                          
    thisClusterVotes    = zeros(1,numPts,'uint16');         %used to resolve conflicts on cluster membership

    while 1     %loop untill convergence

        sqDistToAll = sum((repmat(myMean,1,numPts) - dataPts).^2);    %dist squared from mean to all points still active
        inInds      = find(sqDistToAll < bandSq);               %points within bandWidth
        thisClusterVotes(inInds) = thisClusterVotes(inInds)+1;  %add a vote for all the in points belonging to this cluster


        myOldMean   = myMean;                                   %save the old mean
        myMean      = mean(dataPts(:,inInds),2);                %compute the new mean
        myMembers   = [myMembers inInds];                       %add any point within bandWidth to the cluster
        beenVisitedFlag(myMembers) = 1;                         %mark that these points have been visited

        %*** plot stuff ****
        if plotFlag
            figure(12345),clf,hold on
            if numDim == 2
                plot(dataPts(1,:),dataPts(2,:),'.')
                plot(dataPts(1,myMembers),dataPts(2,myMembers),'ys')
                plot(myMean(1),myMean(2),'go')
                plot(myOldMean(1),myOldMean(2),'rd')
                pause
            end
        end

        %**** if mean doesnt move much stop this cluster ***
        if norm(myMean-myOldMean) < stopThresh

            %check for merge posibilities
            mergeWith = 0;
            for cN = 1:numClust
                distToOther = norm(myMean-clustCent(:,cN));     %distance from posible new clust max to old clust max
                if distToOther < bandWidth/2                    %if its within bandwidth/2 merge new and old
                    mergeWith = cN;
                    break;
                end
            end


            if mergeWith > 0    % something to merge
                clustCent(:,mergeWith)       = 0.5*(myMean+clustCent(:,mergeWith));             %record the max as the mean of the two merged (I know biased twoards new ones)
                %clustMembsCell{mergeWith}    = unique([clustMembsCell{mergeWith} myMembers]);   %record which points inside 
                clusterVotes(mergeWith,:)    = clusterVotes(mergeWith,:) + thisClusterVotes;    %add these votes to the merged cluster
            else    %its a new cluster
                numClust                    = numClust+1                   %increment clusters
                clustCent(:,numClust)       = myMean;                       %record the mean  
                %clustMembsCell{numClust}    = myMembers;                    %store my members
                clusterVotes(numClust,:)    = thisClusterVotes;
            end

            break;
        end

    end


    initPtInds      = find(beenVisitedFlag == 0);           %we can initialize with any of the points not yet visited
    numInitPts      = length(initPtInds);                   %number of active points in set

end

[val,data2cluster] = max(clusterVotes,[],1);                %a point belongs to the cluster with the most votes

%*** If they want the cluster2data cell find it for them
if nargout > 2
    cluster2dataCell = cell(numClust,1);
    for cN = 1:numClust
        myMembers = find(data2cluster == cN);
        cluster2dataCell{cN} = myMembers;
    end
end
```

This is the test code I am using to try and get the Mean Shift program to work:

```
clear
profile on

nPtsPerClust = 250;
nClust  = 3;
totalNumPts = nPtsPerClust*nClust;
m(:,1) = [1 1];
m(:,2) = [-1 -1];
m(:,3) = [1 -1];
var = .6;
bandwidth = .75;
clustMed = [];
%clustCent;


x = var*randn(2,nPtsPerClust*nClust);
%*** build the point set
for i = 1:nClust
    x(:,1+(i-1)*nPtsPerClust:(i)*nPtsPerClust)       = x(:,1+(i-1)*nPtsPerClust:(i)*nPtsPerClust) + repmat(m(:,i),1,nPtsPerClust);   
end

tic
[clustCent,point2cluster,clustMembsCell] = MeanShiftCluster(x,bandwidth);
toc

numClust = length(clustMembsCell)


figure(10),clf,hold on
cVec = 'bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk';%, cVec = [cVec cVec];
for k = 1:min(numClust,length(cVec))
    myMembers = clustMembsCell{k};
    myClustCen = clustCent(:,k);
    plot(x(1,myMembers),x(2,myMembers),[cVec(k) '.'])
    plot(myClustCen(1),myClustCen(2),'o','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor',cVec(k), 'MarkerSize',10)

end
title(['no shifting, numClust:' int2str(numClust)])
```

The test script generates random data `X`.  In my case. I want to use the matrix `D` of size 516 x 19 but I am not sure how to adapt my data to this function.  The function is returning results that are not agreeing with my understanding of the algorithm.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The input requires a `numDim x numPts` dataset.  Because your matrix is 516 x 19, I'm assuming you have 516 data points with 19 features for each point.... can't you just transpose the matrix then use the script?  Make it 19 x 516 so that it is compatible with the Mean Shift script

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for the answer but I change my matrix now 19*515 and the result is not reasonable , I get 495 clusters, I think that i have to to do some pretraitement, like he do with m and x. please help

Comment: What do you mean by "not reasonable?" What are you trying to cluster?

Comment: when I tried Xmeans and DBSCAN i find é and 4 cluster, i think that it is not logical to have 495 clusters for 515 points!!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: Hello, I have a database of physical and try to make clustering without giving the number of clusters as input, for that I sought algorithms that can help me achieve my task, I tried DBSCAN and XMEAN I gives the number of cluster min and max and  I find 2 clusters for XMEAN and 4 for DBSCAN, now I try to do the same thing with mean shift that seems not working  properly on my data cause I find 495 clusters for 515 objects.